# How to compare array of object based on key and value and delete object

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have below data in const rows.

```
const rows = {
      "selected_parameter_value": [
        {
          "parameter_value": "a",
          "label_value": "a"
        },
        {
          "parameter_value": "d",
          "label_value": "d"
        }
      ]
    };
```

I want to compare each and every object of `const rows.selected_parameter_value` with `parameter_value` and `label_value` from `this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value`.

And delete those objects from `this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value` which are not present in `const rows.selected_parameter_value`

**For example -**

In the `const rows.selected_parameter_value`, only `a` and `d` object are present, `b` and `c` are not present.

So remove object whose parameter and label values are b and c from `this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value`.

```
this.selectedParameterContext = {
          'records': [
            {
              'selected_parameter_value': [{
                'parameter_value': 'a',
                'label_value': 'a'
              },
              {
                'parameter_value': 'b',
                'label_value': 'b',
              }]
            },
            {
              'selected_parameter_value': [{
                'parameter_value': 'c',
                'label_value': 'c'
              },
              {
                'parameter_value': 'd',
                'label_value': 'd',
              }]
            }]
        };
```

**Expected Output**

```
this.selectedParameterContext = {
  'records': [
    {
      'selected_parameter_value': [{
        'parameter_value': 'a',
        'label_value': 'a'
      }]
    },
    {
      'selected_parameter_value': [
        {
          'parameter_value': 'd',
          'label_value': 'd',
        }]
    }]
};
```

**Below code**

```
deleteContextData(rows ) { 
    const paramArray = rows.selected_parameter_value;
    const newArrayData = this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value;
    const removeMatchingData = (paramArray, toCompareWith) => {
      return paramArray.filter(({ label_value }) => !toCompareWith.some(compareObj => compareObj.label_value === label_value));
    }
    console.log(removeMatchingData(paramArray, newArrayData),"newarray");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to loop though `this.selectedParameterContext.records`
- then inside first loop, second loop though `record.selected_parameter_value`
- then use `rows.selected_parameter_value.find(...)` to validate
- then use `.splice(...)` to remove item from `this.selectedParameterContext.records`
- or add required data to array

```js
const rows = {
  "selected_parameter_value": [
    {
      "parameter_value": "a",
      "label_value": "a"
    },
    {
      "parameter_value": "d",
      "label_value": "d"
    }
  ]
};

const selectedParameterContext = {
  'records': [
  {
    'selected_parameter_value': [
      {
        'parameter_value': 'a',
        'label_value': 'a'
      },
      {
        'parameter_value': 'b',
        'label_value': 'b',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'selected_parameter_value': [
      {
        'parameter_value': 'c',
        'label_value': 'c'
      },
      {
        'parameter_value': 'd',
        'label_value': 'd',
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
};

selectedParameterContext.records.forEach(function(record, recordIndex) {
  record.selected_parameter_value.forEach(function(parameter, parameterIndex) {
    const isValid = rows.selected_parameter_value.find(function(item) {
      return parameter.parameter_value === item.parameter_value && parameter.label_value === item.label_value;
    });
    if (!isValid) {
      selectedParameterContext.records[recordIndex].selected_parameter_value.splice(parameterIndex, 1);
    }
  });
});

console.log('selectedParameterContext: ', selectedParameterContext);
```

### For new array variable

```js
const rows = {
      "selected_parameter_value": [
        {
          "parameter_value": "a",
          "label_value": "a"
        },
        {
          "parameter_value": "d",
          "label_value": "d"
        }
      ]
    };

    const selectedParameterContext = {
      'records': [
      {
        'selected_parameter_value': [
          {
            'parameter_value': 'a',
            'label_value': 'a'
          },
          {
            'parameter_value': 'b',
            'label_value': 'b',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'selected_parameter_value': [
          {
            'parameter_value': 'c',
            'label_value': 'c'
          },
          {
            'parameter_value': 'd',
            'label_value': 'd',
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
    };
    
    // Building new array variable
    const newSelectedParameterContext = {
      'records': []
    };

    selectedParameterContext.records.forEach(function(record, recordIndex) {
      const newSelectedParameterValues = [];
      record.selected_parameter_value.forEach(function(parameter, parameterIndex) {
        const isValid = rows.selected_parameter_value.find(function(item) {
          return parameter.parameter_value === item.parameter_value && parameter.label_value === item.label_value;
        });
        if (isValid) {
          newSelectedParameterValues.push(parameter);
        }
      });
      newSelectedParameterContext.records.push({'selected_parameter_value': newSelectedParameterValues});
    });

    console.log('newSelectedParameterContext: ', newSelectedParameterContext);
```

Comment: Can u plz help me with some code..i tried bt it wont work for me.

Comment: @saurabh, check updated answer with demo code

Comment: Hi its working fine when i am checking with mockk data for ex  const selectedParameterContext but when i replace  const selectedParameterContext with this.selectedParameterContext  its throwing error. i have data in this.selectedParameterContext not in const selectedParameterContext

Comment: Can u push this in new variable and return data into it.

Comment: @saurabh, please have look at "For new array variable" section.

Answer (score 0):

your data initialized as `const`. It is mean that variable is not mutable. So I suggest you to rebuild like this.

```js
const selectedParameterContext = {
  'records': [
    {
      'selected_parameter_value': [{
        'parameter_value': 'a',
        'label_value': 'a'
      },
      {
        'parameter_value': 'b',
        'label_value': 'b',
      }]
    },
    {
      'selected_parameter_value': [{
        'parameter_value': 'c',
        'label_value': 'c'
      },
      {
        'parameter_value': 'd',
        'label_value': 'd',
      }]
    }]
};

var selectedParameterContext2 = {
  'records': []
}

selectedParameterContext.records.forEach(e=>{
  var records = [];
  e.selected_parameter_value.forEach(f=>{
    if(f.parameter_value==='a'||f.parameter_value==='d')
      records.push(f)
    
  })
  selectedParameterContext2.records.push({'selected_parameter_value': records})
})

console.log(selectedParameterContext2)
```

Comment: Any time you have a `forEach` with a `push` inside, you can probably write it as a `map`.

Comment: But i dont want harcoded compares with key and value, It should be dynamic, and need to collect data from const rows.selected_parameter_value.
here in below output, a and d are present, thats why we want to splice object b and c from selectedParameterContext. and need to keep a and c values.
 `const rows = {
      "selected_parameter_value": [
        {
          "parameter_value": "a",
          "label_value": "a"
        },
        {
          "parameter_value": "d",
          "label_value": "d"
        }
      ]
    };`

Comment: Your output is correct bt i want dynamic replacement for below code  if(f.parameter_value==='a'||f.parameter_value==='d'), here u have added hardcoded a and d, i want this values to be compare from const rows.selected_parameter_value

Comment: so, what do the real condition you want?

Comment: I want it to compare with rows.selected_parameter_value and match with parameter_value and label_value in place of  hardcoded a and d .(f.parameter_value==='a'||f.parameter_value==='d')